# cannot create directory 'device-tree': Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, kernel, device-tree

I am on linux operating system. 
I am Trying to Load device tree Overlays via Configfs.

I tried below steps:

```
$ sudo su
# mount -t configfs none /sys/kernel/config
```

The mount was successful. however when I try to create a directory, I get error:

```
mkdir -p /sys/kernel/config/device-tree/overlays/
```

```
mkdir: cannot create directory 'device-tree': Operation not permitted
```

I am having trouble creating a device-tree folder in config.

I used Kernel Version: 4.19.73
I have CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS=y in kernel.

Best Regards
Sami

Comment: Might be interesting for anybody stumbling upon the same problem (maybe it helps): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747665/mkdir-in-configfs-not-permitted